# how to use the StartCoroutine method

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have tried to use a StartCoroutine on a IEnumerator method but its not working.

It keeps saying that the method can not be turned into a string but I'm not trying to turn it into a string. this is my code:

```
StartCoroutine(PowerupCountdownRoutine());


IEnumerator PowerupCountdownRoutine()
{
   yield return new WaitForSeconds(7);
   hasPowerup = false
}
```

Comment: Could you show us the error your getting?

Comment: You should show the error and the entire script. It may be involving another region of the script that isn't visible to us.

Comment: the error is: cannot convert from 'method group' to 'string'

Comment: Besides the fact that you're missing a Semicolon at hasPowerup = false, Your code runs. You will have to give more if you want an answer.

Comment: This is part of code: public bool hasPowerup = false; 
    private float powerUpStrength = 15.0f;
    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.CompareTag("PowerUp"))
        {
            hasPowerup = true;
            Destroy(other.gameObject);
            powerupIndicator.gameObject.SetActive(true);
            StartCoroutine(PowerupCountdownRoutine());
        }
    }

    IEnumerable PowerupCountdownRoutine()
    {
        hasPowerup = false;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(7);
        powerupIndicator.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }

Answer (score 0):

You should write `nameof(@name of the method@)`in the parameter  -`StartCoroutine(nameof(PowerupCountdownRoutine))`